# Unable to connect sockets with SSL certifcate signed by CA

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a Socket Server running on Ubuntu 18.04 which I am trying to run with SSL/TLS. First I used a self-signed certificate and the code works fine but now I am trying to use a 90-day free SSL certificate signed by ZeroSSL and it doesn't work. Below are the error messages I received on the server and client side upon connection request.

**Server side error:** `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:852)`

**Client side error:** `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)`

**Server Code:**

```
import ssl
import socket

IP = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 2021
server_cert = "/home/ubuntu/chandral/ssl_socket_test/Certificates/Ubuntu/certificate.crt"
#server_cert = "/home/ubuntu/chandral/ssl_socket_test/Certificates/Ubuntu/ca_bundle.crt"
server_key = "/home/ubuntu/chandral/SSL/server.key"
context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=server_cert, keyfile=server_key)
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
secure_server_socket = context.wrap_socket(server_socket, server_side=True)
secure_server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
secure_server_socket.listen(5)
print("listening for connections")
while True:
    client_socket, address = secure_server_socket.accept()
    print("IP/URL of client:", address)
```

**Client Code:**

```
import ssl
import socket

IP = "192.168.1.1" # IP changed in this post for confidentiality
PORT = 2021
server_sni_hostname = "example.com" # Domain changed in this post for confidentiality
context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
secure_client_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=False, server_hostname=server_sni_hostname)
secure_client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
secure_client_socket.send(b"Hello World")
```

Comment: The contents of your `certificate.crt` is unknown but it is important to the question. My guess is that you are simply missing the necessary intermediate certificates (`ca_bundle.crt`) and only provide the leaf certificate. You need to cat `certificate.crt` and `ca_bundle.crt` together and use the result and not only the leaf certificate.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now, had to manually enter a new line between the two certificates in the merged file. Please post this as an answer so that I can upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server_cert = "/home/ubuntu/chandral/ssl_socket_test/Certificates/Ubuntu/certificate.crt"
#server_cert = "/home/ubuntu/chandral/ssl_socket_test/Certificates/Ubuntu/ca_bundle.crt"
```

ZeroSSL [provides three files](https://zerossl.com/help/download-certificate/): `certificate.crt` is the leaf certificate of the server, `private.key` the private key (`server.key` in your code) and `ca_bundle.crt` the intermediate certificates and the root certificates.

A server must provide both the leaf certificate and all chain certificates so that the client [can build the trust chain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity) to the local root CA certificate. To create such setup you need to concatenate the contents of `certificate.crt` with `ca_bundle.crt` and use the result with `context.load_cert_chain(...)`. Note that it might be necessary to add an explicite newline after the `certificate.crt` in case this is missing at the end of the file. Note also that the self-signed root CA (the last certificate in `ca_bundle.crt`) does not need to be included since it will be ignored by the client anyway and instead the local root CA will be used. It is actually recommended to leave this out.